# Select Top nth group by time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have this result set snippet,

```
DateAndTime         Date        Hr  Min Tag Val
11/15/2011 0:00:29  11/15/2011  0   0   47  0.084000006318092
11/15/2011 0:00:59  11/15/2011  0   0   47  0.086000002920628
11/15/2011 0:00:13  11/15/2011  0   0   47  0.084000006318092
11/15/2011 0:00:44  11/15/2011  0   0   47  0.087000004947186
11/15/2011 0:05:06  11/15/2011  0   5   47  0.088500000536442
11/15/2011 0:05:21  11/15/2011  0   5   47  0.084500007331371
11/15/2011 0:05:51  11/15/2011  0   5   47  0.086000002920628
11/15/2011 0:05:36  11/15/2011  0   5   47  0.088000006973743
11/15/2011 0:10:41  11/15/2011  0   10  47  0.086000002920628
11/15/2011 0:10:56  11/15/2011  0   10  47  0.089500002563000
11/15/2011 0:10:09  11/15/2011  0   10  47  0.086500003933907
11/15/2011 0:10:25  11/15/2011  0   10  47  0.089000001549721
11/15/2011 0:15:45  11/15/2011  0   15  47  0.089000001549721
11/15/2011 0:15:14  11/15/2011  0   15  47  0.087500005960465
11/15/2011 0:15:29  11/15/2011  0   15  47  0.089500002563000
11/15/2011 0:20:48  11/15/2011  0   20  47  0.106000006198883
11/15/2011 0:20:03  11/15/2011  0   20  47  0.109500005841255
11/15/2011 0:20:18  11/15/2011  0   20  47  0.104500003159046
11/15/2011 0:20:33  11/15/2011  0   20  47  0.109000004827976
```

I only want to return a single row for minute 0, minute 5, minute 10 and so forth

Comment: And wich row do you want to choose?

Comment: Does this link help? http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18011/1186

Comment: first or last of the Minute group which ever just need 1 record from each minute group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should work in all RDBMSs (however, I'm not able to test it at the moment):

```
SELECT actual.DateAndTime, actual.Tag, actual.Val
FROM ResultTable actual
LEFT JOIN ResultTable exclude
ON exclude.Date = actual.Date
AND exclude.Hr = actual.Hr
AND exclude.Min = actual.Min
AND exclude.DateAndTime > actual.DateAndTime
WHERE exclude.DateAndTime IS NULL
```

... which should net you the 'latest' rows per-minute.

Comment: I think, it will return duplicate rows if DataAndTime found same for value in Min Column. In this case the solution provided by me will worked.

Comment: @Romil - Yes, you're correct - this will return duplicates if `DateAndTime` is not unique.  Hopefully, if that's a timestamp, it will be granular enough for the OP's need.  Your solution _does_ solve this issue (or would if you included enough of the columns in the comparisons).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Minutes VARCHAR(1000) 
;WITH MyRecords AS
(
   SELECT TOP 3 Distinct Min FROM TableName
)


SELECT @Minutes = COALESCE(@Minutes + ', ', '') + MINFROM MyRecords 

PRINT @Minutes
```

Result: 0, 5, 10

If you need to add minute you can easily add before @Minutes :)

Comment: What?  This isn't what the OP wants at all; he's looking for the _entire_ row, at each distinct minute value (top or bottom are specified).  Your solution is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
       id = IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) 
INTO   #temp 
FROM   MyTable 
ORDER  BY [min] 

SELECT o.* 
FROM   #temp o 
WHERE  o.id = (SELECT Min(id) 
               FROM   #temp t 
               WHERE  t.[Min] = o.[Min])
```

Comment: It's SQL Server 2k row_number() over is for Sql2k5 and up.  Thanks tho.

Comment: Unless there are specific _performance_ considerations, I'd avoid (explicitly) creating a temporary table.  Also (contrary to your claims), not all RDBMSs will support 'automatic' temp-tables this way (although I'll defer to you about this happening on all versions of SQL Server).  You also need to add more columns to your comparison, or you're not going to get completely correct results (ie minute 5 from 2:00 and minute 5 from 3:00, and different days, too).

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you want window functions, but they are not available in SQL Server 2000.

Here is an alternative:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select date, hour, min, min(datetime) as mindatetime
      from t
      group by date, hour, min
     ) tsum
     on t.datetime = tsum.mindatetime
```

This assumes that the datetime field is unique.  Otherwise, if you have an id in the column, you could use that instead.